# How to run one java method per scenario

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

With cucumber you write a scenario like so:

```
Scenario: Foo bar works as intended
    Given foo exists
    When I bar
    Then foo bar
```

And in the java code you must have a method per step definition like so

```
@Given("foo exists")
public void foo_exists() {}
@When("i bar")
public void i_bar() {}
@Then("foo bar")
public void foo_bar() {}
```

Is there any way to only have one java method run per scenario, rather than multiple java methods run per step definition in the scenario?

So for example, something like:

```
@Scenario("Foo bar works as intended")
public void foo_bar_works_as_intended() {}
```

EDIT: One idea I've come up with is to have no-op java methods for every stepdef and have an `@After` hook to run after every scenario. I can perform my per-scenario assertions in this after hook by reasoning on the name of the scenario retrieved from the `Scenario` object in the hook. I think that will work but I'm wondering if there are other cleaner ways or if my suggested way won't actually work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it however you want, the BDD model is to offer a better understanding for all involved in the project (both technical and non-technical).

```
Scenario: Foo bar works as intended
  Given some context
  When I do some action
  Then the results are displayed
```

BDD is a set of guidelines to describe your functionalities in a way that anyone can understand and after that to also read the generated report easily.

Using `@After` hook won't display it nicely in the report, as Gherkin step.
Also you cannot distinct between steps/actions and validation steps OR between positive steps/actions and negative steps/actions

But if is easier for you then you can do something like:

```
 @Given("Requesting registration for (.*) works as expected")
 public void registerRequestWithWorkAsExpected(String someCase) {
   // someCase could be user with valid address or with invalid address or..
   //do Registration then some validation
 }
```

BDD is just a tool, use it how it is best for you, but following BDD guide and best practices ensures that you add business value to your automation.

> Why add an extra layer(BDD/Cucumber/Gherkin/Business layer) if you don't need it? I would suggest to use other approach than BDD if you don't benefit from BDD advantages, like TDD with TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't and for good reasons

1. If your test fails you want to know where in the scenario it fails
2. Steps are designed to be re-used across many different scenarios, your approach would remove this capability for re-use.